# Querying the Datastore in python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Greetings!

I am trying to work with a single column in the datatstore, I can view and display the contents, like this:

```
q = test.all()
q.filter("adjclose =", "adjclose")
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM test")

results = q.fetch(5)
for p in results:
    p1 = p.adjclose     
    print "The value is --> %f" % (p.adjclose)
```

however i need to calculate the historical values with the adjclose column, and I am not able to get over the errors

```
for c in range(len(p1)-1):
    TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

here is my code!

```
for c in range(len(p1)-1):
    p1.append(p1[c+1]-p1[c]/p1[c])
    p2 = (p1[c+1]-p1[c]/p1[c])
    print "the p1 value<--> %f" % (p2)
    print "dfd %f" %(p1)
```

new to python, any help will be greatly appreciated!

thanks in advance

Ray

HERE IS THE COMPLETE CODE

```
class CalHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        que = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * from test")
        user_list = que.fetch(limit=100)

        doRender(
            self,
            'memberscreen2.htm',
            {'user_list': user_list} )


q = test.all()
q.filter("adjclose =", "adjclose")
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM test")

results = q.fetch(5)
for p in results:
    p1 = p.adjclose     
    print "The value is --> %f" % (p.adjclose)
    for c in range(len(p1)-1):
        p1.append(p1[c+1]-p1[c]/p1[c])
        print "the p1 value<--> %f" % (p2)
        print "dfd %f" %(p1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
for c in xrange(p1-1)
```

Essentially, it sounds like p1 already contains the len, so you can just use it directly.  Also, note that using the `xrange` function is usually a bit faster than `range`.  The reason being that `xrange` returns an iterator while `range` builds a list.  In other words, if you did `range(1000000)`, it would create a list of a million integers!

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the value bound to `p1` doesn't have a length. That makes sense, because it's a float (also in the error message).

I suspect that what you meant to type was `p` instead of `p1`. This is a great example of why you shouldn't use meaningless variable names. This would be a lot easier to spot if the names were something like `current_result` (instead of `p`) and `current_adjclose` instead of `p1`.

It looks like you might be attempting to do some sort of transformation in your inner loop (it's not 100% clear because of the variable names). If so, that's crying out for you to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Also, it looks like you are possibly trying to reuse variables; don't. There's not a shortage of them, after all, and it makes it hard to choose meaningful variable names.